# I need help to get data sent from an instrument via udp protocol

Tags: sockets, udp

i have an instrument that measures so2 and i have a standard program that makes me see the data, but i need to connect the instrument to a server and send all the data to a database. I used wireshark to see how it comunicate with the software, but i don't understand what method to use to make my program. Here i have the wireshark dump:

[image]

the red circle indicates the measure that the instrument made.
P.S. sorry for my bad eng

Comment: Are you looking to write your own code, or do you want a third party app? In the first case, what programming language? In the second: [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: I want to write my own code, i know was thinking to go with python or java or maybe php because i use them daily, but i never did such thing. I only develop management software for businesses

Comment: Once you decide what language you need to figure out how to parse the data. It looks like it uses standard [ASCII codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html): `\001` is `SOH` (start of heading). `\002` is `STX` (start of text), etc. After that, I guess the data is comma separated. Or see if there is an existing library for your device.

Comment: So i want to use python, i don't know how to make my pc and the instrument talk. I tested with the socket example, but i didn't had any reult. I know that the program change port on every connection, but the instrument one is always 53700.

Comment: Please add whatever code you already have. There are a million examples of UDP clients on the web. [Python - UDP client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674211)

Comment: i think that: i need to make the code to establish a connection , to send the request to get the data and make a listener to get the data back, but i don't actually know how to make that in python.

Comment: i made that piece of code from that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my question as i'm about to show:
i made a listener and a caller;

caller:

```
`from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '192.168.1.99'
PORT_NUMBER = 53700
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind(('192.168.1.100', 57806))

while True:
    data = bytes.fromhex('014630303430335230303102313103')
    mySocket.sendto(data,(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
    exit()`
```

listener:

```
`from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
PORT_NUMBER = 57806
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

while True:
        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data)
sys.ext()`
```

i saw on wireshark that if i sent a request packet copied from the ones that i already have, the instrument would give me back the response; so i setupped a listener on the a choosen port, and now i get all the data!
[image]

the highlighted packet is the one i sent from the caller script.